# Getting DHCP to issue an address to Windows 7 Embedded

Tags: dhcp, windows-embedded-7

I have 3 Windows 7 Embedded: Standard machines running on my network. The network is managed by a Domain Controller running Windows Server 2016 Standard. The Domain Controller is running DHCP and DNS. Previously the system was all static. When I took over I started up the DHCP server and it is working for all the machines except these 3 machines. The 3 machines were statically set to 192.168.4.101 through 103 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0. To connect them with the DHCP I set them to automatically get addresses and DNS.

When I did this the 3 systems will not get addresses. They will default 169.254.252.47 with Subnet mask 255.255.0.0. Looks like this.

```
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-B3-01-C1
 DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
 Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 169.252.213.37(Preferred)
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
 DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 
 NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

So I started searching google and found a few solutions. First I tried the top solution for the registry key from [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3e26affd-bb91-460a-b5fa-c7c0496c927c/how-to-disable-autoconfiguration-ipv4-?forum=winserverNIS) post. I did this fix and restarted. After restart the connection looked like this:

```
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-B3-01-C1
 DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
 Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
 DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
                                     10.0.0.2
 NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

It would not get an address. The DHCP server does not see the computer either. So I went back to to the registry and deleted the key and went to [this](https://techridez.com/blog/how-to-fix-autoconfiguration-ipv4-address-issue-windows-server-2012-r2/) post.

This disables the DHCP client and reenables it after a restart. I don't see how this did anything but I tried it. When I did that I checked my DHCP server and in the Leases section and it added an entry called BAD_ADDRESS and the description says that the address was being used. So I deleted that entry and it still does not work.

So I guess what I am asking is do I need to get the AutoConfiguration to be disabled to get these Windows 7 Embedded machines to pull a DHCP address or is it the fact that Embedded is so compartmentalized I can't get one? Is it possible to have these machines get an address assigned by DHCP?